# jQuery modal popup not opening up after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, popup

I have a piece of jquery code written like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnSingleSave", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var originalState = $(".hideIt").clone();
    $(".hideitAmazon").animate({
        height: ["70"],
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, 800, "linear", function () {
        $('.loader').show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            var el = document.getElementById("cancelButton");
            el.click();
            $('.loader').hide();
        }, 2800);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".hideIt").replaceWith(originalState);
        }, 3500);
    });
});
```

As you can see here guys I've triggered an animation button on the onclick event which animates the modal popup (the animations rolls up the popup and makes it disappear after the event is done...

What the problem here is if the user triggers this events and then clicks somewhere else on form (meaning the popup looses the focus)... Then when I try calling the popup to open up next time, it doesn't shows up on the form unless I  refresh the page completely.

I've figured out that I need to do something with this event:

```
$("#modalFadeOut").focusout(function () {
    $('#modalFadeOut').trigger("reset");
});
```

And this is how the outer layer of the popup looks like:

```
<div class="remodal" style="width:80%" id="modalFadeOut" data-remodal-id="modal3">

</div>
```

I need to somehow reset the popup if the user clicks somewhere else upon the animation, so that I can re-show it again when user clicks on the event which triggers the popup's opening...

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: can you provide your necessary HTML. Where are `.hideIt`, `.hideitAmazon`, `.loader` ?

Comment: inspect(F12 on windows) your code to check for any syntax error!

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)  so we can see what is going on?